# Confusion in dereferencing pointer to 2d and 3d vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector, dereference

I'm unable to wrap my head around dereferencing 2d and 3d vectors.
First, I'm creating a 2d vector (of size 4x3) and filling it up:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> two_dim (4, std::vector<float> (3));
for(size_t r = 0; r < two_dim.size(); r++) {
    for(size_t c = 0; c < two_dim[0].size(); c++) {
        two_dim[r][c] = r*two_dim[0].size() + c + 100;
        std::cout << two_dim[r][c] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Then, I'm trying to get the pointer to the vector two_dim, and trying to dereference it:

```
auto two_dim_ptr = two_dim.data();
std::cout << "dereferencing-1: " << (*two_dim_ptr)[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "dereferencing-2: " << (float)(*two_dim_ptr)[0] << std::endl;
```

Both these techniques work (correct value) untill I reach the end of first row (after indices 0, 1, 2). When I try to dereference index 3 onwards, the value is 0. That is, for (*two_dim_ptr)[3], which I thought should point to two_dim[1][0].

Now, for a 3-d vector, when I do

```
auto three_dim_ptr = three_dim.data();
std::cout << "dereferencing: = " << (float)(*three_dim_ptr)[0] << std::endl;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
invalid cast from type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<float> >, std::vector<float> >::value_type’ {aka ‘std::vector<float>’} to type ‘float’
```

But, when I do `((float*) three_dim_ptr())[0]`, I don't get an error, but the value seem to be garbage.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?
I guess I'm not able to understanding how to dereference multi-dimensional vectors here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You just cannot continue after the end of an array and expect to find something else. (Even if it so happens that more data is there, the language rules forbid it). And about the cast - `(float*)something` tells the compiler "I know there is a float there, so just shut up and do it". And so the compiler will no longer tell you that it doesn't work. That's all.

Comment: The expression `(*three_dim_ptr)[0]` is a `std::vector<float>`, not a `float`

Comment: It seems like you believe that the vectors' contents are laid out end-to-end like arrays. They're not.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using C-style casts. If you are getting type errors, and add those casts to "fix" that, your program instead has undefined behaviour. Stop using `vec.data()` to get a pointer, use the member functions of vector.

To get a `float` out of a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>`, you need 3 indexes, e.g. `three_dim[a][b][c]`

What it sounds like you want is a [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) pointing to the data of a `std::vector<float>`.